# how to add a website to aws ec2 instance, no target

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webserver, cloud, amazon-route53

I've a nice little ec2 instance, I've logged in the console, updated the YUM, started the httpd, but the IP doesn't work in the browser.

my httpd is up on chkconfig:  httpd           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off

Thought it would be as listed on my connect from public DNS, same as I connect to console through.   I've used the S3 server into the properties on the instance and enabled static website hosting, just to test it before using PHP.  Even created a like bucket, trying to use my domain name from the Route 53, but the Route 53 also shows "No Targets Available" in the S3 (or any other).

Comment: At least to me, your description is incredibly confusing. You have Apache up, you go to your browser, put in http://(your ip or elasticip here) and you should get the default apache page. If you installed PHP and put `phpinfo()` there you should get that. If you want your website up you need to reroute  your DNS entry from your current host to your new IP.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, found it.  Was a security issue, but here is the process, in two quick url's.

Tutorial: Installing a LAMP Web Server on Amazon Linux
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html?shortFooter=true

But it says if ***it doesn't work, check the security groups***, and a couple of clicks later you're looking at this.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html?shortFooter=true

Go into the security group settings and add http from pull down and it's done.

Also, the second part where there isn't a target, be sure and associate the elasticIP (created in the AWS services console) and sure enough a web server is up and running.  Once you've the elasticIP address simply add it to the route 53 rule set(s).